# Unexpected end of JSON input - Angular 2 and Slim 3 PHP app

Tags: php, angular, slim-3

I am currently develop an Angular 2 frontend and Slim 3 PHP backend. I receive the following error when i try to make a post request.

Angular Service

```
create(user: any) {
        console.log(user);
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/public/auth/signup', user , options)
            .map((response: Response)  =>response.json());
    }
```

Angular component where i use the service above

```
register(event, full_name, email, password) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.userService.create(JSON.stringify({"full_name": full_name,"email": email,"password": password}))
            .subscribe(
                data => this.postData = data,
                error => alert(error),
                () => console.log("Finished")
            );
    }
```

And finally PHP part

```
public function postSignUp($request,$response)
        {

            $validation = $this->validator->validate($request, [
                'full_name' => v::notEmpty()->alpha(),
                'email' => v::noWhitespace()->notEmpty()->email()->EmailAvailable(),
                'password' => v::noWhitespace()->notEmpty(),
            ]);

            if($validation->failed()) {
                return $response;
            }

            $new_user = $this->db->insert("users", [
                "full_name" => $request->getParam('full_name'),
                "email" => $request->getParam('email'),
                "password" => password_hash($request->getParam('password'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
            ]);

            $this->flash->addMessage('info', 'You have been signed up!');

            $auth = $this->auth->attempt(
                $request->getParam('email'),
                $request->getParam('password')
            );

            $registered_user = [
                "id" => $new_user,
                "full_name" => $request->getParam('full_name'),
                "email" => $request->getParam('email')
            ];

            echo json_encode($registered_user);
            return $response;
        }
```

Any ideas of what seem to be the problem? Thank you!

Comment: Where does the error appear? On Angular 2 side?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending a form, you need to use URLSearchParams.

This should work:

Component:

```
register(event, full_name, email, password) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.userService.create(full_name, email, password)
            .subscribe(
                data => this.postData = data,
                error => alert(error),
                () => console.log("Finished")
            );
    }
```

Service:

```
create(full_name, email, password) {
        let body = new URLSearchParams()
        body.set('full_name', full_name);
        body.set('email', email);
        body.set('password', password);

        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/public/auth/signup', body.toString(), options)
            .map((response: Response)  =>response.json());
    }
```

Comment: Codrut, did this answer help you? :)